# Reading multiple screen clicks and displaying the same on edittext

Tags: android

Am new to Android, and am building a simple calculator app. I want to read the multiple clicks made on the screen (i.e numbers) and display the same in edittext.

Kindly find the code below, in the button's onclicklistener event, am displaying  the numbers directly in edittext. With this piece of code, the displayed numbers in edittext are getting overwritten (i.e it is not getting appended). For example when I click '1', it appears correctly, and next when I click '2', it appears as '2', instead of "12". I know my logic is wrong here, but how can I make the characters to append in edittext?

Code:

```
    button00.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText01.setText("0");
        }
    });

    button01.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText01.setText("1");
        }
    });

    button02.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            EditText01.setText("2");
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText()` doesn't depend on what was in the box previously, so you'll have to just do some simple string concatenating:

```
String prevText = EditText01.getText().toString();
EditText01.setText(prevText + "2");
```

Since `getText()` returns an `Editable`, you have to convert it to a String, but after that point, yeah, just do the above for each number. You could probably further optimize it by having a class StringBuilder, and just using StringBuilder.append() to add and set the value, but the above should work just fine.